# How do i make python look for a specific word

Tags: python

So i have this code:

```
x = 1
while x <= 2:
    text = input("> ")
    to_deny = "!?/"
    find=["find subsystem"]
    if any(char in text for char in to_deny):
        print("text contains restricted characters")
        quit()
    if any(char in text for char in find):
        print(f"finding subsystem: {text}")
    if text == "quit":
        quit()
    elif text == "clear":
       import os
       os.system("clear")
    else:
       print(f"running {text}....")
```

And i want to make it so when you say " find subsystem" (cringe, i know) it will instead print "finding subsystem: (name of subsystem goes here)" and not "finding subsystem: (subsystem) running (subsystem)...."
I have tried everything i could possibly think of but my stupid 2 brain cell mind only tried:
Using lists (i forgot how to make one :/)
Using a dictionary (forgot how to make one too)

Comment: Where is the name of the subsystem? Do you mean they enter something like `find subsystem abc` and you want to extract `abc` from that?

Comment: You could use a regular expression for this: `find subsystem (.*)`. The capture group will get the subsystem name.,

Comment: Let me assure you that web has a ton of tutorials on Python lists and dictionaries. All you need is to search.

Comment: Not sure why you added "closed" to your title, but I rolled that back, as it really doesn't make sense: 1) your question isn't closed and 2) you can delete a question if it shouldn't be here. But things like "closed", or adding answers to questions, are not valid edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the mutually exclusive operations that don't result in a `break` or `continue` in a single `if...elif...else` chain so that you don't "fall through" from one into the next.

```
import os

to_deny = "!?/"
find = "find subsystem "
while True:
    text = input("> ")
    if any(char in text for char in to_deny):
        print("text contains restricted characters")
        break
    if text == "quit":
        break

    if find in text:
        text = text.replace(find, "")
        print(f"finding subsystem: {text}")
    elif text == "clear":
        os.system("clear")
    else:
        print(f"running {text}....")
```

```
> find subsystem abc
finding subsystem: abc
> blargh
running blargh....
>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, really depends on your goals and how much code you want to change around.  A quick and easy is to regex the `text` before you print it like this:

```
import re
.
.
.
if any(char in text for char in find):
        text = re.sub("^find subsystem\s*","" ,text)
        print(f"finding subsystem: {text}")
.
.
.
```

which would give you

```
>  find subsystem test123
finding subsystem:  find subsystem test123
running  find subsystem test123....
>
```

You could write a regex with capture and print that instead.  Also wouldn't be a bad idea to just take a refresh on the Python basics for flow control, list and dicts, like here: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python-3